# ssh connection though ssh2_connect failed

Tags: php, shell

I want to connect to a remote server to execute a commmand.

Here my php:

```
<?php

$dir='ChemAliveMolOpt/TEST';
$remote_file = $dir.'/inputfile';

$command="/home/bomble/ChemAliveMolOpt/ChemAliveExec/ChemAliveMolOpt ".$remote_file;

$connection = ssh2_connect('bomble@40.127.184.54', 21);
ssh2_exec($connection,  $command);

?>
```

Here my errors:

> PHP Warning:  ssh2_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: Name or service not known in php shell code on line 1 PHP
>   Warning:  ssh2_connect(): Unable to connect to bomble@40.127.184.54 on
>   port 21 in php shell code on line 1 PHP Warning:  ssh2_connect():
>   Unable to connect to bomble@40.127.184.54 in php shell code on line 1

If I connect to the sever using ssh bomble@40.127.184.54 it is connecting properly.

Any advices?

Comment: can you connect (with what credentials) to the ssh server?

Comment: Why are you trying to connect to port 21 (ftp), shouldn't you be connecting to port 22 (ssh) ?

Comment: @Laetis Did you find the solution? If yes, then please, post an answer, it'll be really helpful for others who are stuck.

Answer (score 4):

You get the error because you try to connect to a host name that cannot be resolved. This is, because 'bomble@40.127.184.54' is *not* a valid host name. That string cannot be resolved to an ip address, obviously.

The documentation is pretty clear about how to use the `ssh2_connect()` command: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-connect.php

It clearly states that the first argument to the function has to be a *host name*, not something *containing* a host name besides other stuff.

---

BTW: also the port number you specify (port 21) is surprising. Are you *really* sure you have a ssh server listening on that port? Though technically possible that would be highly surprising...

Comment: So the solution ?

Comment: @famas23 Em, the solution would be to use a valid host name, so "40.127.184.54" instead of "bomble@40.127.184.54". I thought that was clear from the answer, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

My script was working on Windows but was not working on Linux.

I found this solution worked for me.

Change the `Selinux` paramater.

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```

Answer (score -1):

Add and enable **php_ssh2** extension in xampp or wamp. Make sure you will use the correct php_ssh2 extension. Otherwise, it will not work.